How to correctly call a rate limited API?
I have an app that needs to request some data from an API endpoint. The data returned from this API endpoint are paginated. Assume I am retrieving 1000 records for every call. For each of these records I make 4 more requests to fetch related data. Also, assume there are a total of 11,0000 records i.e. 11 pages.
The API allows for a max of 60 requests/minute. For each page retrieved I map through it to fetch related records for some properties.
My attempt was to create a function that observes a rate limit by using kotlin's delay. The function is as follows:
suspend fun <T> observeRateLimit(delayInMillis: Long, block: suspend () -> T): Deferred<T> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    launch { delay(delayInMillis) }
    async { block() }
}

This function is then used inside a function that calls the endpoint.
suspend fun populate(nextPage: Int?) {
   getAllRecords(nextPage).map { result ->
        val records = result.data.map {
             // Wait for 1 minute
             observeRateLimitAsync(60000) {
                 val id = it.id
                 val entity = it.mapToEntity()

                 // Fetch related record (1)
                 val related1 = fetchRelatedRecord1(id)

                 // Fetch related record (2)
                 val related2 = fetchRelatedRecord2(id)

                 // Fetch related record (3)
                 val related3 = fetchRelatedRecord3(id)

                 // Fetch related record (4)
                 val related4 = fetchRelatedRecord4(id)

                 // Process the entity
                 entity
            }.await()
        }

        // Insert records to DB

        // If next page exists
        if (result.pages.nextUrl != null) populate(records.size + 1000)
   }.flowOn(Dispatcher.IO).collect()
}

This works but as you would have noticed runs pretty slow. Keep in mind there are about 11,000 records.
How do I efficiently retrieve all the records from the API without hitting the rate limit on the server?
I am also interested in other ideas to explore that will allow caching all records from this endpoint in the local DB.
Edit:
Here is what my API interface looks like:
interface ApiService {
    @GET("$path/{id}")
    suspend fun getSubject(@Path("id") id: Int): Result<Response>
}

and the repository:
class Repository @Inject constructor(val apiService: ApiService) {
    suspend fun getSubject(id: Int) = apiService.getSubject(id)
}


Why do you need to download all 11K at once?  Wouldn't it make more sense to download them either as you need them, or just ahead of needing them (for example downloading page 3 in the background while displaying page 2, so the load of page 3 will be instant). If the API is so expensive they need to rate limit it, it's probably not a great idea to load them all upfront.

That is a good question. Even if I were to load them as you suggested, my current implementation is still too slow to fetch a decent amount of the records in a short time period.

As I understand it you need to do the following API calls to get all data:

11 pages (containing 1000 records each)
For each record 4 additional calls: 11 * 1000 * 4 = 44,000

That's 44,011 API calls in total. With a rate-limit of 60 calls per minute that wil be 44,011/60 minutes or just a bit above 12 hours. This is independent of how efficient you make your requests, it's what the endpoint allows as best case.
We obviously cannot help you with making the endpoint faster. What we can do, though, is help you get close to that best case of 12 hours. More like 13, probably, in a real-life example.
With the obvious question if all of this even makes sense cast aside, the best way to do it would be to decouple the rate limiting aspect from the caller. It should be an integral part of the API so that your populate function and the getAllRecords lambda don't need to burden themselves with calculating how long to wait for the next request. Their responsibility should only be to loop over all pages and retrieve the additional, related data.
What needs to be changed depends on how getAllRecords and the fetchRelatedRecord functions actually request data from the API. Since you didn't show us anything about the API surface the following will only show the general approach. Let's assume your API looks like this:
class API {
    suspend fun unlimitedRequest(request: Request): Result {
        // immediately send request to endpoint
    }
}

This will request the data from the endpoint as soon as it is called. Now, instead of directly calling this method from getAllRecords and the fetchRelatedRecord functions, we'll implement a new rateLimitedRequest method that respects the rate limiting behavior of the endpoint and calls unlimitedRequest as soon as possible while also waiting for as long as necessary:
class API(
    maxRequestsCount: Int = 60,
    private val maxRequestsDuration: Duration = 1.minutes,
    private val waitingScope: CoroutineScope,
) {
    private val channel = Channel<Unit>(maxRequestsCount)

    suspend fun rateLimitedRequest(request: Request): Result {
        // Wait for an empty slot in the requests queue by trying to place a token in the channel.
        channel.send(Unit)

        // Do the request.
        val result = unlimitedRequest(request)

        // Remove a token from the channel after maxRequestsDuration.
        waitingScope.launch {
            delay(maxRequestsDuration)
            channel.tryReceive()
        }

        return result
    }

    private suspend fun unlimitedRequest(request: Request): Result {
        // immediately send request to endpoint
    }
}

Your API now needs to be initialized with maxRequestsCount as the number of requests that are allowed per maxRequestsDuration. For your case this will be 60 per 1.minutes. The waitingScope is the coroutine scope that will be used for waiting until the next request can be sent.
How this works
The Channel that is used is like a blocking queue with a capacity of maxRequestsCount (for you it will be 60). When the queue is not full it means that a request can be safely made. With channel.send(Unit) we try to occupy a slot in the queue. If the queue is full (that is, we reached the rate limit), this function waits until a slot becomes free.
When we have occupied a slot in the queue we are now free to send a request to the endpoint. When we're finished we need to release our slot in the queue. Now, when we would just call channel.tryReceive() (that removes an element from the channel) then the next request waiting to enter the queue would immediately call the endpoint again. What we want instead is to delay that by maxRequestsDuration (which is done in a separate coroutine so the result can be retuned immediately).
If the capacity of the queue (maxRequestsCount) would be 1, this would simply delay the next request made by a minute. The rate limiting behavior would be 1/minute.
If the capacity would be set to 2, the next request would be made immediately (because there is one other free slot in the queue), but both, the first and the second request will only release their slot after a minute so the queue is now full. A third request would have to wait for one of the first two requests to release their slot. This effectively results in a rate limiting behavior of 2/minute.
A capacity of 60 therefore allows 60 requests per minute.

If you actually want to proceed with this despite the 13 hours this will take in total you should definetly cache your results. This could be done with a Room database.

Thank you @Leviathan, for such a beautiful piece. How would this be used in the context of my example?

Well, that all depends on your API. Whatever getAllRecords and fetchRelatedRecord* do to actually receive data, they should now use rateLimitedRequest instead of unlimitedRequest (which is just a placeholder for what you actually use). Just make sure all requests are channelled through rateLimitedRequest so no request can bypass the rate-limiting restrictions.

I see what you mean. In my case getAllRecords is simply a call to a retrofit service method. I will give it a try at the earliest.

Great, in that case you could use the API class from my answer to wrap the retrofit instance so it cannot be accessed except through rateLimitedRequest.

I just got into implementing this and could not figure out how this can wrap my retrofit instance. Please keep in mind I am dependency injection in place. Looking forward to your response, thanks.

I don't know how you build your requests with retrofit but the execution of such a request must be placed in unlimitedRequest. Adapt the parameter and return types accordingly. Use your dependency injection framework to Inject whatever is needed for that request into API (the retrofit instance, the service api, whatever). Just make it so that none of your code can access the endpoint except by calling rateLimitedRequest.

I have included a sample api service and a repo implementation in an edit to the question.

Yes, that looks great, then you can just do what I wrote in my previous comment and you are all set.
